# What is the automorphism group of the projective line minus $n$ points?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, projective-geometry, automorphism-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\AGL}{\operatorname{AGL}}\DeclareMathOperator{\PGL}{\operatorname{PGL}}$What is the automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1$ minus $n$ points (let's say over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ if it matters). I want to consider the removed points without order. I can do small cases by hand but it seems hard in general and it seems to depend on which points are removed.

Here's what I have thought about so far:

- $n = 0$: The automorphism group of $\mathbb P^1$ is $\PGL_2(k)$
- $n = 1$: The automorphism group of $\mathbb A^1$ is $\AGL(1)$.
- $n = 2$: The automorphism group of $\mathbb G_m$ is $\mathbb Z/2 \ltimes k^\times$.
- $n = 3$: Since $\PGL_2$ acts three transitively, it doesn't matter which points we remove. Any automorphism of $\mathbb P^1 - \{0,1,\infty\}$ will extend to an automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ fixing $\{0,1,\infty\}$ as a set and is determined by what it does to this set. We get all of $S_3$ in this case.
- $n = 4$: Any automorphism has to preserve the cross ratio and every permutation that does so is obtainable. So we get the Klein $4$ group - $\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2$ in the generic case.

I don't know what happens for $n \geq 5$. We can get non trivial automorphisms for large $n$ by doing the following: Pick a finite subgroup of $\PGL_2(k)$ (these are classified) and pick any finite subset of $\mathbb P^1$ and remove the entire orbit of this set by the finite subgroup.

Also generically, I believe there are no automorphisms for $n\geq 5$ by the following argument: We require all $4$ element subsets to have distinct cross ratios and since automorphisms have to preserve the cross ratio, this means that all $4$ element subsets are preserved. But this implies that the automorphism is trivial.

Comment: The $n=2$ case should be $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ltimes k^\times$, no?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct! I guess you mean the $\mathbb Z/2$ acts by inversion on $k^\times$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: For $n \geq 5$ there are no generic automorphisms, and we have automorphisms in a special case using the construction you said. What more do you want to say?

Comment: Is it too much to hope for a classification of the exceptional cases?

Comment: Every configuration with any automorphisms has an automorphism of order $p$ for some prime $p$. This can happen only if $p$ divides $n$, $n-1$, or $n-2$, in which case the $n$ points consist of $0,1,$ or $2$ fixed points, respectively, together with some number of orbits of size $p$. This writes the exceptional cases as a finite union of explicit subvarieties.

Comment: In case $n=4$, $k = \mathbb{C}$, consider the set consisting of $0$ and the three third roots of unity. The automorphism group of this set contains an element of order $3$, so it cannot be the Klein four group.

Comment: @WillSawin That seems like it deserves to be an accepted answer.

Comment: An immediate remark, still worth saying explicitly, is that for $n\ge 3$ (removing a set $F$ of $n$ points) the action of the automorphism group on $F$ is faithful, and in particular the automorphism group is always finite, not only generically (this is implicit in Will Sawin's answer).

Comment: it is strange to me to say "I do not know what happens for $n\ge 5$" and then after to say what happens: you have always a finite group and a finite set of orbits of this group. This is the only possibility. You can get all case by looking at the list of finite groups and giving then all possible orbits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $n \geq 5$, we can describe the locus  of configurations that have nontrivial automorphisms. To do this, note that if there is any nontrivial automorphism, there is an automorphism of order $p$ for some prime $p$. Such an automorphism acts on $\mathbb P^1$ with two fixed points and the remaining points orbits of size $p$.

So the automorphism restricts to $\mathbb P^1$ minus $n$ points if and only if $n=ap+b$ for some $a \in \mathbb N$ and $b \in \{0,1,2\}$, and those $n$ points consist of $b$ of the fixed points as well as $a$ orbits of size $p$.

The space of such configurations has dimension $a$ for any given automorphism, hence $a+2$ in total, which is at most $\frac{n}{p}+ 2 \leq \frac{n}{2} + 2 <n$.